# How to show an activity icon in an action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

In my Android application, I'm trying to use `setlogo()`, `ActionBar` and `android:icon` but they don't work as expected: Output shows absolutely no icon and I'm really confusing about it. I need your help.

My code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

        //recyclerview
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_main);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mainactivity,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_add_contects:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddContects.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }    
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an icon in your `ActionBar` you need to call

`setHomeAsUpIndicator()` instead of `setIcon()`

Like this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set any image in toolbar using the following code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/camera"
                        android:src="@drawable/camera"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/search"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```